# Speeding up merge operation in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 different nodes with label **Class** and **Parents**. These nodes are connected with **hasParents** Relationship. There are 4 million Class nodes, 700K Parents nodes. I wanted to create a **Sibling** Relationship between the Class nodes. I did the following query:

```
Match (A:Class)-[:hasParents]-> (B:Parents) <-[:hasParents]-(C:Class) Merge (A)-[:Sibling]-[C]
```

This query is taking ages to complete. I have indexed in both `class_id` and `parent_id` property of `Class` and `Parents` node. I am using Neo4j version 2.1.6. Any suggestion to speed this up.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the indices won't help the query since the properties are not referenced anywhere in the query.

With 700K `Parent` nodes and 4M `Class` nodes, you have on average 5.7 classes per parent. With 5 classes under one parent, there are 15 `Sibling` relationships, so there would be more than 10M relationships to create for the whole graph.

That's **a lot** for one transaction, you're almost guaranteed to hit an OutOfMemory error.

To avoid that, you should batch changes into several smaller transactions.

I'd use a marker label to manage the progression. First, mark all the parents:

```
MATCH (p:Parent) SET p:ToProcess
```

Then, repeatedly select a subset of the nodes that remain to be processed, and connect the siblings:

```
MATCH (p:ToProcess)
REMOVE p:ToProcess
WITH p
LIMIT 1000
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<-[:hasParents]-(c:Class)
WITH p, collect(c) AS children
FOREACH (c1 IN children |
    FOREACH (c2 IN filter(c IN children WHERE c <> c1) |
        MERGE (c1)-[:Sibling]-(c2)))
RETURN count(p)
```

As the query returns the number of parents that were processed, you just repeat it until it returns 0. At that point, no parent has the `ToProcess` label anymore.

Comment: I ran the query from last one hour . I do not see any "Sibling" relationship populated in my database.

Comment: One execution of the query with the `LIMIT` does not return in 1 hour? Do you have pathological cases with hundreds of classes for one parent? Try decreasing the limit to 100 or even 10, then.